# Preserving cookies between sessions

Tags: selenium

I need to make sure that a browser is trusted every time the session is when performing Selenium script in Node.js (If the browser is not trusted by the server it resets in MFA with SMSes which I would like to avoid).
In Puppeteer it is simple by:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,
    userDataDir: "./user_data"});
```

I would love to stay with puppeteer because of that but I have a dropdown selector on the page accessible only by name or xpath and page and page.select requires CSS selector:-(.

So I moved back to Selenium, but there I have this persistency problem:

At the end of a session I have:

```
var allCokies = await driver.manage().getCookies();  fs.writeFile("/Users/matnikr/Documents/scrape/selenium/cookies.json",JSON.stringify(allCokies), function(err){
        if (err) {return console.log(err)}
        console.log('file saved');})
```

A the begining I have:

```
driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
var allCokies =  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("/Users/matnikr/Documents/angular\ code/Aliorscrape/selenium/cookies.json","utf8"));
   for (var key in allCokies){
        await driver.manage().addCookie(allCokies[key])
    }
    await driver.get('https:*******/do/Login');
```

And every time it feels like "incognito" session is started. Browser is untrusted. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to do the same as you did with Puppeteer? I mean to load a profile. Because it's actually what you did by providing `"./user_data"` as a `userDataDir` value.

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Options } = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

function buildChromeDriver() {
  const options = new Options();
  options.addArguments('user-data-dir=./user_data');

  return new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();
}
```

You can always verify the loaded profile by opening chrome://version in the browser:

```
driver.get('chrome://version');
```

Comment: Wow! Nope. I did not know that Selenium Webdriver supports user data. Thanks. I'll try and confirm.

Comment: I did try it. Worked during first pass. But during subsequent runs I get error: Error: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use. When I removed the options thinking it got remembered by Chrome, when I run it it simply hangs now.

Comment: I think It didn't get remembered but actually you have opened two browsers with the same profile. It might be a good idea to create a new, separated profile only for testing purposes and load it instead of the default one.

Comment: Thanks. When I moved the code to Windows 10 instead of Mac, everything works, so I guess there are some additional profile issues with Chrome on mac.